# Is it possible to extend a view from within another view in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel

I have a main template that yields content into the middle of the page. So far ive been creating views that extend the main template and then define the content.

```
@extends('app')

@section('content')

@stop
```

Im in a place now where i have about 20 views that are kinda similar, but a little different. Rather than create 20 different views that i have to maintain i would like to extend another view from within a view. I dont want to do this for every view so i dont want to make a change to the app template since not all views require this template.

So something like this.

```
@extends('app')

@section('content')

@extends('posttemplate')
    @section('postimage')
    <img.....
    @stop

    @section('customdata')

    @stop
@stop
```

If i was to use raw php without laravel i might do something where i declare variables and then include the template that will just output the variables that i have defined.

Comment: What is wrong with `partials`?

Comment: Would this allow me to template the contents of a yield though? For the moment the only solution i can think of is to use include and just pre define variables before the include

Comment: Try with `include`. Hope will solve the issue.